# link_to different model activeadmin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a Model with serialized column 'data' that contains values like this:-

```
data: {:samplekey=>[40, 50]}
```

Inside ActiveAdmin show, I want to create links to another model named Example using ids saved in the data above.
I tried the following, but its not working:-

```
    row :data do |d|
        if !d.data.nil?
            d.data[:samplekey].each do |k|
                link_to("#{k}", admin_example_path(Example.find(k)))
            end
        end
    end
```

Output is like this(without any links):-

```
Data    [40, 50]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the final implementation that is working.

I am using a method inside my model to return a list of objects:

```
def get_examples
  result = Array.new
  if !self.data.nil?
    self.data[:samplekey].each do |x|
      result << Example.find(x)
    end
  end
  result
end
```

and inside the admin controller show action I did this:-

```
    row :example_data do |x|
        x.get_examples.map{|e| link_to("#{e.id}", admin_example_path(e))}.join("<br/>").html_safe
    end
```